# install visual studio on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: .net, linux, visual-studio, ubuntu, installation

I am trying to install  visual studio on my Ubuntu machine , I tried to to install it using WINE but without any success , because it is need Microsoft .net framework 4.0 , and I already installed version 4.7 . 
I removed 4.7 version and tried to install  4.0 using this commands

```
 sudo apt-get install winetricks
 winetricks dotnet40
```

it throw a lot of errors during the installation operation , but then it said .netframework installed successfully , 
the errors which I have like this

> $env WINEARCH=win32 WINEPREFIX=~/.wine32 winetricks dotnet40 Using
>   winetricks 20180815 - sha256sum:
>   29e664ec1e879271a33167bf367deaa188cbe803d44b540e692bd669c44a2804 with
>   wine-3.0.3 (Ubuntu 3.0.3-2) and WINEARCH=win32 Executing w_do_call
>   dotnet40 Executing load_dotnet40
>   ------------------------------------------------------ dotnet40 does not yet fully work or install on wine.  Caveat emptor.
>   ------------------------------------------------------ Executing w_do_call remove_mono Executing load_remove_mono
>
> ### ------------------------------------------------------ Mono does not appear to be installed.
>
> ------------------------------------------------------ Working around wine bug 34803
>   ------------------------------------------------------ reg: Sistem belirtilen kayıt anahtarını veya değeri bulamadı reg: Sistem
>   belirtilen kayıt anahtarını veya değeri bulamadı reg: Sistem
>   belirtilen kayıt anahtarını veya değeri bulamadı Executing rm -f
>   /home/batuhan/.wine32/dosdevices/c:/windows/system32/mscoree.dll
>   Executing w_do_call winxp Executing load_winxp Setting Windows version
>   to winxp Executing wine regedit C:\windows\Temp_winxp\set-winver.reg
>   ------------------------------------------------------ Running /usr/bin/wineserver -w. This will hang until all wine processes in
>   prefix=/home/batuhan/.wine32 terminate
>   ------------------------------------------------------ Executing cd /home/batuhan/.cache/winetricks/dotnet40
>   0032:err:winediag:SECUR32_initNTLMSP ntlm_auth was not found or is
>   outdated. Make sure that ntlm_auth >= 3.0.25 is in your path. Usually,
>   you can find it in the winbind package of your distribution.
>   0035:err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for
>   installroot 0035:err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry
>   key for installroot 0035:err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading
>   registry key for installroot 0035:err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error
>   reading registry key for installroot 0035:err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim
>   error reading registry key for installroot
>   0035:err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for
>   installroot 0035:err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry
>   key for installroot 0035:err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading
>   registry key for installroot 015f:err:ole:CoGetContextToken apartment
>   not initialised 014f:err:ole:CoReleaseMarshalData
>   IMarshal::ReleaseMarshalData failed with error 0x8001011d
>   0162:err:ole:StdMarshalImpl_UnmarshalInterface Apartment not
>   initialized 0162:err:ole:CoUnmarshalInterface
>   IMarshal::UnmarshalInterface failed, 0x800401f0
>   0175:err:ole:CoGetContextToken apartment not initialised
>   0164:err:ole:CoReleaseMarshalData IMarshal::ReleaseMarshalData failed
>   with error 0x8001011d 0186:err:ole:CoGetContextToken apartment not
>   initialised 0179:err:ole:CoReleaseMarshalData
>   IMarshal::ReleaseMarshalData failed with error 0x800101

1d

Answer (score 0):

You can install ntlm_auth via python

```
sudo -H pip install ntlm-auth
```

This will place ntlm_auth in your path.